# Namespace for Restrictions.Eq in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

This sounds like such a dumb question but I've spent too long looking for the 'Restrictions' object when attempting something like this...

```
Objects objs = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Objects ))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ObjectName", objName))
```

I'm using nHibernate 2.2 I believe and have added references nHibernate, log4Net, lesi.Collections to my project and have searched through the object browser to find this elusive class.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is your **problem**? Doesn't it compile? If you use Visual Studio, it should allow you to easily import namespaces. Did you import NHibernate.Criteria (or was it Criterion?)?

Comment: There is no NH 2.2. There is NH 2.1.2 and NH 3.0 Alpha 1.

Comment: OK - kinda makes sense however, I'm missing that namespace.  I have the nHibernate.dll referenced in my assembly and intellisense doesn't pick it up nor the object browser.  I've justed checked my version of nHibernate which I can confirm is v2.1.2GA, the nHibernate.DLL has the runtime version of v2.0.50727 and the version of 1.2.0.3001.  

Any thoughts?

Comment: The assembly version of 2.1.2GA is 2.1.2.4000. You have the wrong dll.

Comment: OK, re-downloaded the zip binaries from sourceforge for the 'NHibernate-2.1.2.GA-bin.zip' and still getting the same problem of the namespace not being available...

Comment: do you have a namespace in your application that is called Restrictions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

namespace - NHibernate.Criterion
class - NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions
Assembly - NHibernate.dll

Comment: OK - kinda makes sense however, I'm missing that namespace.  I have the nHibernate.dll referenced in my assembly and intellisense doesn't pick it up nor the object browser.  I've justed checked my version of nHibernate which I can confirm is v2.1.2GA, the nHibernate.DLL has the runtime version of v2.0.50727 and the version of 1.2.0.3001.  

Any thoughts?

Comment: is it only intellisense that's the issue?have u tried compiling your project? what errors, if any, do you get on compilation?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is NHibernate.Criterion.

Comment: OK - kinda makes sense however, I'm missing that namespace.  I have the nHibernate.dll referenced in my assembly and intellisense doesn't pick it up nor the object browser.  I've justed checked my version of nHibernate which I can confirm is v2.1.2GA, the nHibernate.DLL has the runtime version of v2.0.50727 and the version of 1.2.0.3001.  

Any thoughts?